# working directory win32 visual studio

Tags: c++, git, winapi, visual-studio-2013

I have `createprocess` witch `lpCurrentDirectory`  is Set to `NULL`. I have changed my working directory to `..\Debug` in property window.
[image]

Then create process finds .exe file and program works without problems. Then I push my program with git to server. Then I create folder and clone from server that program. Problem is that when I or any other person clones that program working directory changes to default.
[image]

Then createprocess can't find .exe file. Most important thing here is that program must run on other computers without any modifications. So my questions would be:

- How can I make my working directory permanent?
- if It can't be done what other options to this problem i have? And how to implement them?

Most important thing is that paths can't be written like this L"G:\CppProjects\ConsoleApplication1"
because it won't work from other directory or other computers without small modifications. Any ideas are wellcome.

Comment: Pass the full path of the executable to CreateProcess.

Comment: But how to pass it? It will change depending on where other people will clone that file. because there is two programs in solution. One creates that  .exe other is controller to that .exe. and from one computer to other path would be different.

Comment: Find out the directory where your executable lives and compose the full path using that.

Comment: Well it would be $(SolutionDir)/Debug. It always would be there. Is there any function to find solution folder path. I can find current working directory path but it is a bit deeper so to navigate from it would be harder because then I need to go back one folder and then go to Debug folder.

Comment: Why are you deploying your solution? But in any case, you want to go up a folder, just do so. That's not difficult. What option do you have?

Comment: Can you be more specific. I don't understand what "deploy your solution" means? I don't have much experience

Comment: Who are these other people running your program? Other developers? If so then everything should be fine for them. But if they are your end users, then they should not have the solution, all the source files etc. You deploy the compiled executables to your end users. The simplest way is to put both executables in the same directory and pass the full path to the executable when you call `CreateProcess`.

Comment: When you say go up the folder. you mean that I need to take my string which has current directory path and try to substract part of it which means last folder than add to that string //Debug ?

Comment: Other developers. Release files works fine because they both are at same folder.

Comment: I haven't got the energy to try to walk you though this. Sorry.

Comment: There is no `CreateProcess` call in your question, so we would have to guess. This isn't valuable for future visitors. Voting to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Debugging settings for Visual Studio projects are considered user-specific, not project-specific. This is because these settings very often contain paths which are only guaranteed to exist on the workstation which sets them up. By design and by default, these settings are not committed to source control.

You CAN share these things by putting the `whatever.vcxproj.user` file (from the same directory as `whatever.vcxproj`) into source control. I wouldn't recommend doing that, however, because this file contains not only debugging settings, but also other workstation/user-specific settings that you may find problematic to share.

Comment: The *Debugging* settings are indeed considered per-user configurations. However, there *is* a clean way to set this up for every user on your team: Specify paths relative to the pre-configured Visual Studio macros (e.g. `$(SolutionDir)`). That makes them valid for every developer, irrespective of where their solutions are. I believe they can be deployed using property sheets. See [Working with Project Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx) to learn, how this works. These property sheets can then be merged into the .vcxproj settings, using the *Property Manager*.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the vcxproj seems to work for me.  NOTE: I had to specify one property group for each of Release|x64, Debug|x64 etc.  It didn't seem to work for me without the conditions.

```
  <!-- Adding this so we default working directory to $(OutDir) so we don't have to manually change that to get test suites to work properly. -->
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory>$(OutDir)</LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory>
    <DebuggerFlavor>WindowsLocalDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory>$(OutDir)</LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory>
    <DebuggerFlavor>WindowsLocalDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>
  </PropertyGroup>
```